# Implement a table using LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, lightning-web-components

I would like to implement a table in Lightning Web Components, which would use standard library components and implement the desired outcome.

This is listing of `table.html` file

```
<template>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Table
                </td>
                <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                    <td key={col} colspan=3>
                        {col}
                    </td>
                </template>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                    <td key={col}>
                        <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td key={col}>
                        <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                    <td key={col}>
                        <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                    </td>
                </template>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                    <template for:each={options} for:item="opt">
                        <td key={opt}>
                            {opt}
                        </td>
                    </template>
                </template>
            </tr>
            <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                <tr key={row}>
                    <td>{row}</td>
                    <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                        <td key={col}>
                            <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                        <td key={col}>
                            <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                        <td key={col}>
                            <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                    </template>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </table>
    </div>    

    <lightning-datatable columns={dataColumns} data={data} key-field="row">

    </lightning-datatable>

</template>
```

This is listing of `table.js` file

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Table extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta', 'Epsilon', 'Zeta', 'Eta', 'Theta', 'Iota', 'Kappa', 'Lambda']
    @track rows = [1, 2, 3, 5]
    @track options = ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3']
    @track data = [{row:1,Alpha:'a1'}, {row:2,Alpha:'a2'}]
    @track dataColumns = this.columns.map(x=>({'label':x, 'fieldName':x}))
}
```

This is how it looks like (desired outcome)
[image]

I tried to use `lightning:layout` and `lightning:layout-item` but I can't achieve the desired replication of standard table tag. Also I tried to use `lightning:datatable` component but this component doesn't support custom output element. Is there any way to achieve this using standard library components?

Is this possible to replace `table` tag by something like "lightning:table" or "aura:grid"?

Comment: what do you mean by ` doesn't support custom output element`?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I mean that I can't put three checkboxes inside one cell using lightning:datatable. I even cannot put a single checkbox inside a cell of a lightning:datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SLDS requires some [special classes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/) in order to make it work. I've taken the liberty of shuffling some of the code around so it looks nicer, but the main point is that you need slds-table, etc. This is not a perfect reproduction of the lightning-datatable (you'll see differences), but hopefully gives you an idea of what you need to do.

```
<template>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th>
                        Table
                    </th>
                    <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                        <th key={col} colspan=3 scope="col">
                            {col}
                        </th>
                    </template>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                        <template for:each={options} for:item="opt">
                            <th key={opt}>
                                {opt}
                            </th>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                        <td key={col}>
                            <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                        <td key={col}>
                            <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                        <td key={col}>
                            <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                        </td>
                    </template>
                </tr>
                <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                    <tr key={row}>
                        <td>{row}</td>
                        <template for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                            <td key={col}>
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                            <td key={col}>
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                            <td key={col}>
                                <lightning-input type="checkbox"></lightning-input>
                            </td>
                        </template>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <lightning-datatable columns={dataColumns} data={data} key-field="row">

    </lightning-datatable>

</template>
```

Comment: so you are still using `table` tag, is that possible to use some standard Lightning library tag, something like "lightning:table" or "aura:grid"?

Comment: My question is about if is this possible to replace `table` tag by  something like "lightning:table" or "aura:grid"

Comment: @Patlatus Nope, all the stuff in the [Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components) is all we get.

Comment: @Patlatus - consider accepting some answers, I noticed you have quite a couple that dont have one =)

Comment: @glls thanks, when there is an acceptable answer I always accepting it, however, something when answer doesn't satisfy me, I consider performing additional research or wait until salesforce implement a feature for a possible satisfactory answer

Comment: You can always update or select a different answer after selecting one